# Android Permission Denial:starting intent

Tags: android, permissions

This security exception is stopping my program to execute completely

```
ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.kite.agm/.KiteActivity } from null (pid=31991, uid=2000) requires null
```

How to fix this thing ?

This is the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kite.agm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/pbird_1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
     <activity android:name="MenuScreen"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
      <activity android:name=".KiteActivity"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:permission="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY" >
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </activity>

     <activity android:name=".GameOver"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
  </application>
```

Comment: show your manifest plz, did you try to add that activity into your manifest file ?

Comment: PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY is deprecated. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to put a period in here

```
<activity android:name="MenuScreen"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

<activity android:name="MenuScreen"
```

should be:

```
<activity android:name=".MenuScreen"
```

Comment: Hey please tick this question as right answer so that others would find it easy to use. Regards,